# Post Hoc for Significant Chi Square Test

Tags: r, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, post-hoc

I have applied Chi square test between Gender and Practice of specific norm (4 levels; Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Quarterly) to check the association.

```
Tabulated statistics: Gender, Practice 

Rows: Gender   Columns: Practice

        1   2   3   4  All

1      14  69  25   7  115
2       7  25  60  23  115
All    21  94  85  30  230

Cell Contents:      Count


Pearson Chi-Square = 47.187, DF = 3, P-Value = 0.000
```

My results are highly significant, now I want to examine that which has more influence for this significant association; Male/ Female. For this propose, which test is more appropriate?

Comment: What kind of variable is Practice? Since you applied a chi square test, I assume it is categorical - if yes, how many levels are there? And what do you mean by "which is more associated"?

Comment: I agree with @ute. Also, questions about how to do things with software are off topic here.

Comment: @ute  "which is more associated"? means Whom? Males or Females.

Comment: @PeterFlom I am not asking about "How to do" I want to know "Which" tests can be used and "how to interpret".

Comment: Ok, J AK my question about "which is more associated" actually meant: in *which way* **more associated** -- how do you measure "more associated", can you give an example (edit your question) if you don't have a statistical term at hand?

Comment: @Ute Between both which is more Male or Female. My q is quite similar to <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512253/understanding-chi-square-post-hoc-test-results>

Comment: I can see that you are editing your question, very good! If you added an example what you mean by more associated, that would be great :-) also refer to similar q improves the qlty of your q.

Comment: @Ute kindly see my comment.

Comment: "between male and female" is clear. "more associated" is unclear. The q you referred to shows an example to explaincan be made up, no matter. Busy users will not click on links in opaque questions but just dont bother wondering

Comment: If "association" means your p value of a chisq whatever tst, then xplain

Comment: gender is associated is general term. I want to know more deeply. Kindly understand it with importance of Post hoc test. Why we use them???

Comment: I second @ute comments, "more associated" needs clarification, in particular when "practice" may be considered as an ordinal variable. By "more associated", do you mean the gender where the cells are making the greatest contribution to the chi-square test result? Or do you mean something along the lines of "Does being a woman increase the frequence of practice, compared to men"? These are different things. Maybe you should explain what your research question is, it would help answering you.

Comment: You need to explain what YOU mean by more associated. Give an example for less and more associated . The question is too general and cannot be answered. It is like "I want to buy a car for less than 50000$. Which one should I take?" a good advisor would then ask me: what do you need the car for. Go for @J-J-J s suggestion and explain your scientific question

Comment: To your last comment:it seems to me that you read about post hoc tests in the question you linked to. It does not necessarily make sense here. The only thing you can check with posthoc is, if your F/M ratio  differs between two given Practice levels.

Comment: @J-J-J I want this  "Does being a woman increase the frequency of practice, compared to men"?

Comment: @Ute yes I want know that contribution for example: male at different levels of practice. I conclude that Gender n paractice are associated but female practice daily, weekly or monthly "more"

Comment: J AK, the whole confusion about "associated" could be a language problem -- if English isn't your native language, could you please try to find synonyms that exactly express what this means? English isn't my native language either, so I am mainly used to words used in scientific papers (for more than 30 years, ghosh...) and you are on the safe side with most other users if you pick a word that I understand :-) I just saw your comment to @J-J-J : put this into your question, it helps immensely

Comment: P. S. Hints for your next improvement of your question: Maybe associated = engaged? Be slightly more wordy. Is practice = exercise in a gym? // don't use abbreviations, wirite question, not q

Comment: P. P. S:Asking specifically about minitab reduces significantly the number of users who are able to give a full answer. When you have gotten an answer about your *statistical* question, you can google about how to do it in minitab, because you then know what to search for. / / give approximate numbers: how many FM, how many in each level. It does not need to be precise, but we need to know if you are talking about 10, 100, 1000 ore more people. The answer may depend on it.

Comment: Men ans women are, by definition, equally associated. The variable is "sex" and the question asked by chi-square is whether sex is associated with practice. 

If your question is, rather "do men or women practice more" then I would do ordinal regression, with practice as the DV and sex as the IV.

Comment: @Ute nice suggestions.

Comment: @PeterFlom's comment would be an answer to the question he phrases. If this is your question, then it should be stated in the post - generally, when asking for statistical help with a real world data analysis, it helps immensely to give a *brief* description of the scientific context, including what your data look like (how many variables, what is the relationship between variables that you are interested in). When I read the word "associated"  it immediately triggers the way some people use it when they describe statistical correlation, like "lung cancer is associated with smoking".

Comment: thn why post hoc chi square test is used. <https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512253/understanding-chi-square-post-hoc-test-results?noredirect=1&lq=1>

Comment: Good edit, much better to understand now! You got a significant result, and want to know if this is more due to M or more to F, right? I doubt if this is possible to say: the test checks if there is a difference between M and F, and said "yes, there is a big difference". But when you compare two populations, and find out that they are different, how can you say one of them has more influence? Do you want to check the residuals for the 8 combination levels and look which group has more significant ones?

Comment: post hoc chi square in the linked question wants to find out which of six Journal contributed most to the association. You can do [post hoc analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_analysis) when you have at least three groups, because you have only an overall result. In your case, there are only two gender levels, so there is no reason or possibility to do post hoc tests.

Comment: Sorry, can I jump in with a stupid question - I would have thought that J AK could test whether proportion of women or men is larger or smaller than expected within each of the groups?

Comment: Yeah, this would be a reasonable thing to look at, @Sointu :-) I seem to have said earlier that OP can only compare two practice levels with posthoc tests, but maybe you can post an answer and suggest that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm inexperienced with categorical data and got scared I've been doing everything wrong :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already got what you need from the above discussion, but you can run chi-square post hoc tests in R using, for instance chisq.posthoc.test, like this

```
t              #make your count table an R object, let's call it t
   1  2  3  4
F 14 69 25  7  #I assumed top row is women and bottom row is men
M  7 25 60 23

library(chisq.posthoc.test)

chisq.posthoc.test(t, method="holm")

  Dimension     Value         1         2         3         4
1         F Residuals  1.602430  5.901783 -4.781217 -3.132624
2         F  p values  0.545302  0.000000  0.000012  0.010395
3         M Residuals -1.602430 -5.901783  4.781217  3.132624
4         M  p values  0.545302  0.000000  0.000012  0.010395

#you can choose the correction method from the p.adjust methods
```

So, the post hoc test suggests that with p < .05 as the critical value there are significantly more women in Practice=2 and significantly more men in Practice=3 and Practice=4. No significant gender differences are found for Practice=1 group (if top row is men and bottom row women, the results for Practice 2-4 are of course the opposite to the above).

Comment: Thank you, @Sointu, great - I think this is actually what OP meant (+1) : "Ute yes I want know that contribution for example: male at different levels of practice. I conclude that Gender n paractice are associated but female practice daily, weekly or monthly "more" "